# Swift/SpriteKit Collision with Custom Class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision

I have a class that creates variables for multiple SpriteNods which looks like this:

```
class Enemy {

var speed:Float = 0.0
var guy:SKSpriteNode
var currentFrame = 0
var randomFrame = 0
var moving = false
var rotationSpeed:CGFloat = 1.0
var angle = 0.0
var range = 1.2
var yPos = CGFloat()
var rotationDirection:Int = 0
var preLocation:CGFloat = 0
var health:Int = 0

init(speed:Float, guy:SKSpriteNode, rotationSpeed:CGFloat, rotationDirection:Int, preLocation:CGFloat, health:Int) {

    self.speed = speed
    self.guy = guy
    self.rotationSpeed = rotationSpeed
    self.rotationDirection = rotationDirection
    self.preLocation = preLocation
    self.health = health


}
```

A SpriteNode is then applied to the Enemy like this:

```
func addEnemy(#named: String, speed:Float, yPos: CGFloat, rotationSpeed:CGFloat, rotationDirection:Int, preLocation:CGFloat, health:Int) {

    var enemyNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: named)

    enemyNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyNode.texture, alphaThreshold: 0, size: enemyNode.size)
    enemyNode.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    enemyNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue
    enemyNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue | ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue
    enemyNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Hero.rawValue | ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue
    enemyNode.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    var enemy = Enemy(speed: speed, guy: enemyNode, rotationSpeed: rotationSpeed, rotationDirection: rotationDirection, preLocation: preLocation, health: health)
    enemys.append(enemy)
    enemy.guy.name = named
    resetEnemy(enemyNode, yPos: yPos)
    enemy.yPos = enemyNode.position.y
    addChild(enemyNode)

}
```

Now i have the problem that in the didBeginContact function i only get the SpriteNodes back so i can't get to the enemy specific variables, like health.

So i want to know how i can reference the enemy class to the spritenode, so i can use it in the didBeginContact function.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason for not inheriting from `SKSpriteNode` by `Enemy` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this exact problem. You need to cast the node as the object you are looking for. In didBeginContact it would be something like this:

```
if let myEnemy = contact.bodyA.node as? Enemy {
     myEnemy.speed = 99
}
```